# Unable to disable ssh with password on remote linux

Tags: ssh

I set up my public+private key on my NAS and works perfectly. However i am unable to disable the password prompt after this:
PS C:\Users\Stefan> ssh root@192.168.0.101 -p 9222 -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
root@192.168.0.101's password:
and still asks for a password. My sshd_config file is as follows:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.97 2015/08/06 14:53:21 deraadt Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.
#TOS_USE_PORT
Port 9222
#LocalPort_TGM
Port 9223
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 6
MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
#AllowUsers root admin Cosmin
#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# enable DSCP QoS values (per RFC-4594)
#IPQoS AF21 AF11

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
#Match LocalPort  9223
#ForceCommand script -t 2>/mnt/appdata/helplog/$USER-$UID-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").time -a /mnt/appdata/helplog/$USER-$UID-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").his
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

So my PasswordAuthentication is set to no on the server I am trying to ssh to.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Did you reload or restart `sshd` after updating the config?

Comment: yes, i tried restarting both ssh and sshd services

Comment: Maybe check the docs for your specific NAS? They might have done something funky.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a password on your keys when creating them then you will have to type the password while using them. You might have to research Linux Expect script to input the password for you...